# Native FIle System API read system folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to read the content of a folder located in the desktop but the getDirectory is not triggering.

```
(<any>window).requestFileSystem =
  (<any>window).requestFileSystem || (<any>window).webkitRequestFileSystem;

(<any>window).requestFileSystem(
  (<any>window).PERSISTENT,
  1024 * 1024,
  fs => {
    fs.root.getDirectory("~/Desktop/Print", { create: true }, dirEntry => {
      console.log(dirEntry);
    });
  }
);
```

the fs is a fileSystem:

```
name: "http_localhost_4200:Persistent"
root: DirectoryEntry {
  isFile: false, 
  isDirectory: true, 
  name: "", 
  fullPath: "/", 
  filesystem: DOMFileSystem
}
```

can you help figure this out?

Comment: On which browser you are testing that? [Can I use - NFS](https://caniuse.com/#feat=native-filesystem-api) - check this page, it is avaiable only on Chrome with enabled flag

Comment: I'm using Chrome 80.0 with Native File System API flag enabled.